# Trying to use JDBC with Eclipse: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

As I understand it, this error is because Eclipse is using the wrong JDK or something. I am using ojdbc7.jar, which says it is to be used with JDK 7. How can I see what JDK Eclipse is pointing at in order to solve this? Does anyone have other tips for this problem?

Comment: What is your project jdk ? What is your oracle database version?

Answer (score 2):

Project (Right Click) -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> JRE System Library[`<version>`] -> Edit (Click) -> Execution Environment (Select JavaSE-1.7)